# MIPS - How to perform a shift on a string?

Tags: string, mips, shift

I'm very new to MIPS programming, and I've been stuck on a problem I've been attempting to program. I realize what I'm trying to do may be silly, but bear with me please! Here's a description of what I'm attempting to do.

Let's say that I have this string: "~~Hello World!". I want to obtain the string "Hello World!" by shifting this string left by two characters. So far, my closest attempt at performing such an operation is this:

Let the register $t0 contain the string "~~Hello World!". I want to perform a left shift of 2 bits on this string and store in the register $t1.

```
.data
     output1: .asciiz "The value in $t1 is: "

.text
     sll $t1, $t0, 2   # attempt at shifting left by 2 bits 
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0, output1
     syscall           # print "The value in $t1 is: "
     li $v0, 4
     move $a0, $t1
     syscall           # print the contents of the register $t1
```

However, when I assemble these instructions, I'm met with an address out of range error. Can anybody point out where I'm going wrong, and perhaps what I should do to achieve this?

Comment: Instead of putting the solution in the question and putting "Solved" in the title, what you should do in case you've figured it out yourself is to post the solution as an answer. And then you can mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out! Here is an updated code snippet, which now contains the working instructions. I'll leave this post up in case it helps anybody else.

```
.data
     output1: .asciiz "The value in $t1 is: "
.text
     add $t0, $t0, 2   # shifts the string left by 2 bits (CORRECT) 
     li $v0, 4
     la $a0, output1
     syscall           # print "The value in $t1 is: "
     li $v0, 4
     move $a0, $t1
     syscall           # print the contents of the register $t1
```